# Return, as objects, rows deleted with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I return the rows deleted as objects? Would I have to query them, delete them, then compare deleted id's with queried id's, or is there an  built-in way?

* I **do not** want to get **how many** rows deleted, I want **the rows's values**

Using PDO with MySql, and returning rows as a "Media" class.

Comment: AFAIK You'd have to query them before deleting them.

Comment: I suppose you could have an `AFTER DELETE` trigger that creates and populates a temporary table from each deleted record.  You could then fetch the contents of that temporary table at a later time using PDO.  However, all that does is reverse the order of `SELECT; DELETE;` to be `DELETE; SELECT;` so I doubt it's worthwhile?  Alternatively, you could create a stored procedure which performs both actions: PDO would merely invoke the one `CALL` command which would return the data that is also deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to query the rows prior to deleting them. UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE only return the number of Rows Affected value. You may be able to extend this functionality with triggers, but personally, that might be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

There are often good reasons for seeking alternatives to deleting rows from databases. It sounds like you might have discovered that already. Have you thought of adding a "flag" e.g. removed = 1 or 0 ?

Comment: In this case I wouldn't need that flag, but that reminded me I could implement a "trash bin" of sorts.